# Trying to use Play 2.5.3 but SBT freezes while resolving dependency

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm using intellij and have followed this doc:

https:// www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25

I changed the `plugins.sbt` like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")
```

Then it gets stuck:

```
[debug]         tried https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.3/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I checked this repository and there's no 2.5.3 version.

What I'm doing wrong?

**This is my build.sbt:**

name := "play"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `play` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc, cache, javaWs

)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+= baseDirectory(_ / "target/web/public/test")

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

**This is my project/plugins.sbt:**

logLevel := Level.Info

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")

***Another problem:***
When i change to 2.4.6, it works, but there's another problem,project refresh failed

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:535)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:535)
at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:157)
```

**My JDK is 1.8**

Comment: Please, edit the question to add `build.sbt` file and also `project/plugins.sbt`. Probably there is a resolver missing. You can also post the result of executing `sbt resolvers`.

Answer (score 0):

The error somehow showing that there is a misspelling in play version like you added, try the following plugins.sbt (this is my sbt that working good for me) remove the plugins that you don't want and add what you are using but becarful for the versions that you use:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.1")


// Not necessary but useful for development
// https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh
//addSbtPlugin("com.jamesward" % "play-auto-refresh" % "0.0.14")
```

You can verify version from : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play

since you use 2.5.x verify the versions under 2_11 not 2_10, like  play_2.11 not  play_2.10 , so check your plugins that using scala 2.11 not 2.10 this what maybe made 2.4.3 works and not 2.5.x .

Comment: Still not work,when i run play 2 app :` [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.3 ...
[debug] sbt-chain-delegate: Checking cache for: dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}
[debug]   tried https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.3/ivys/ivy.xml`

Comment: @Hao did you tried resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
note I changed http to https

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your sbt version is up to date; `project/build.properties` should contain:

```
sbt.version=0.13.11
```

As the latest sbt version includes some new resolvers; you just have to put  the play plugin in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")
```

Comment: I'm sure: sbt.version=0.13.11

Comment: I just checked my ivy cache, and it seems the play sbt-plugin was downloaded from:

http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.3 

And If you want to check the correct sbt version is used, just launch: `sbt sbtVersion`

Comment: It's obviously that your repository is right. I launched sbt sbtVersion,It's really 0.13.11. How to change the repository ?What I'm doing wrong

Comment: Did you simply tried to remove the typesafe resolver in your plugins.sbt ?

Also, sbt added a way to directly configure plugins for the current project; no need to have a `lazy val play...` just adding a line with `enablePlugins(PlayJava)` is enough.